# System is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gulp, systemjs

I have made a little script turning my express server written in TypeScript into JavaScript using Gulp:

```
gulp.task("compile:server", () => {
var tsProject = ts.createProject('./tsconfig.json');
var tsResult = gulp.src('server/**/*.ts')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(ts(tsProject));
return tsResult.js
    .pipe(concat('server.js'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
```

});

The resultant JavaScript looks like this:

```
System.register(['express'], function(exports_1, context_1) {
"use strict";
var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
var express;
var app, PORT, logger;
return {
    setters:[
        function (express_1) {
            express = express_1;
        }],
    execute: function() {
        app = express();
        PORT = 3000;
        logger = function (req, res, next) {
            console.log(Date.now() + ': ' + req.baseUrl);
            next();
        };
        app.use(logger);
        app.listen(PORT);
    }
}
});
```

However, when I run "node server.js", I get the following error:

ReferenceError: System is not defined.

Which I find very weird, since the system.js file is in the same directory as the server.js file. Help's much appreciated.

Comment: Might be that your code is running before `System` has been defined.

Comment: How about adding: var System = require('systemjs');

Comment: @callback, how would I go about fixing that?

Comment: Why are you using systemjs in node?  Change the tsconfig.json to use "commonjs" instead of "system"?

Comment: Why doesn't system work with node though? Answered my question tho.

Comment: System does work with node. The system.js file should not be in the same directory as the server.js file as you state. You should install it with npm, which would make it end up in the node_modules directory. Then you'd import it with an import statement at the top. I agree with Corey Alix though. Just use commonjs, so you don't have to go through all of that.